# property intl does not exist

Tags: react-native, intl

When i am running app without debugger or in release mode i am getting the error that " property intl does not exist ".

I already have jscFlavor in my build.gradle.

```
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'


if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

enableHermes value in project.ext.react is true.

I have tried cleaning and rebuild the app but it is not working now with my RN version 0.64.4